# Merging local git repo changes to a already created github repository

Tags: git, github

I am new to git. We are converting our project from svn to git.

We have a github. We started converting demo projects. I started the conversion process like this

1. Converted svn project to git using `git svn clone` command in my MAC
2. So I got a local repo now with all svn log
3. Created a repo in github. I want to upload my local git repository changes to github repository

How do I do that? Or else please suggest me if there is a different way

Comment: when you create a repo, there should be step by step instructions for what to do.  in a nutshell, you add your changes, commit your changes, and then push your changes.

Comment: @dax Thanks!! Yaa I thought this is the different case, because of reason we are having two different git repos. I first tried copying all svn cloned files including .git into my git cloned directory from github. It throwed an error saying that, the later directory is not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issuing these commands in your local repository will populate your new github project:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo
git push origin master
```

Replace `user/repo` with your github username and the project name. You will be asked for your github username and password.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt thought this would be simple, bcoz of two different repos(github & local). When I tried to push, it said that, you locally didnot have all the github files(here README) because I initiated my github repo with README file. So I did "git pull" first and then "git push"